# Numpy index array of unknown dimensions?

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array, assertion

I need to compare a bunch of numpy arrays with different dimensions, say:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.array([1,2,3],[4,5,6])
assert(a == b[0])
```

How can I do this if I do not know either the shape of a and b, besides that

```
len(shape(a)) == len(shape(b)) - 1
```

and neither do I know which dimension to skip from b. I'd like to use np.index_exp, but that does not seem to help me ...

```
def compare_arrays(a,b,skip_row):
    u = np.index_exp[ ... ]
    assert(a[:] == b[u])
```

Edit
Or to put it otherwise, I wan't to construct slicing if I know the shape of the array and the dimension I want to miss. How do I dynamically create the np.index_exp, if I know the number of dimensions and positions, where to put ":" and where to put "0".

Comment: is np.take what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks,  np.take seems to work on given axis. I could probably use it, but how do I give ":" to define range?

Comment: What do you mean by `skip row` or line?  Or do you mean skip a dimension?

Comment: @hpaulj thanks, I meant dimension, corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was just looking at the code for `apply_along_axis` and `apply_over_axis`, studying how they construct indexing objects.

Lets make a 4d array:

```
In [355]: b=np.ones((2,3,4,3),int)
```

Make a list of `slices` (using list * replicate)

```
In [356]: ind=[slice(None)]*b.ndim

In [357]: b[ind].shape    # same as b[:,:,:,:]
Out[357]: (2, 3, 4, 3)

In [358]: ind[2]=2     # replace one slice with index

In [359]: b[ind].shape   # a slice, indexing on the third dim
Out[359]: (2, 3, 3)
```

Or with your example

```
In [361]: b = np.array([1,2,3],[4,5,6])   # missing []
...
TypeError: data type not understood

In [362]: b = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])

In [366]: ind=[slice(None)]*b.ndim    
In [367]: ind[0]=0
In [368]: a==b[ind]
Out[368]: array([ True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

This indexing is basically the same as `np.take`, but the same idea can be extended to other cases.

I don't quite follow your questions about the use of `:`.  Note that when building an indexing list I use `slice(None)`.  The interpreter translates all indexing `:` into `slice` objects: `[start:stop:step] => slice(start, stop, step)`.

Usually you don't need to use `a[:]==b[0]`; `a==b[0]` is sufficient.  With lists `alist[:]` makes a copy, with arrays it does nothing (unless used on the RHS, `a[:]=...`).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Looks like I was unaware of the "slice()" construction, with this I can indeed construct any kind and any dimension indexes, perfect!